# WebClient is incorrectly trying to start a web server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to migrate my REST client application to use WebClient instead of RestTemplate.
But, when I run my client code, it is apparently trying to start a web server and connect to port 8080, which fails because Tomcat is already running on the port.

I don't want to start a web server.  I just want to connect to an external web server and pull back a response.

Here is the error I get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

Here is my test code:

```
package test.rest.webClient;

import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.hc.core5.net.URIBuilder;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.ResponseSpec;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import test.Path;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebClientTest implements CommandLineRunner {
  @Override
  public void run(String... args) 
  throws Exception {
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
    builder.setScheme("https");
    builder.setHost("marketing.propfinancing.com");
    builder.setPath("/caddata/TXCollin/getByIdAndYear");
    builder.addParameter("id", "37");
    builder.addParameter("year", "2022");

    WebClient client = WebClient.create();
    RequestHeadersUriSpec<?> uriSpec = client.get();
    uriSpec.uri(builder.build());
    uriSpec.header(Path.getApplicationProperties().getProperty("caddata.apiKey.header.name"), 
        Path.getApplicationProperties().getProperty("caddata.apiKey"));
    uriSpec.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    ResponseSpec responseSpec = uriSpec.retrieve();
    ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String,Object>> typeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){};
    Mono<Map<String,Object>> mono = responseSpec.bodyToMono(typeReference);
    Map<String,Object> response = mono.block();
    for( Object key : response.keySet() ) {
      Object value = response.get(key);
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).warn(key+":"+value);
    }
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(WebClientTest.class, args);
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` is a web application running on a web server per default. Thats what it is. Both webclient and resttemplate are just wrappers around the webservers HttpClient. Your RestTemplate application most likely also starts a webserver unless you have told it not to. You can configure it to not start the server. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-no-web-server

Comment: @Toerktumlare This is strange.  I have another class where I use RestTemplate in the same way and I don't get the error.  But, setting the application to no web server did the trick!  Please post that as an answer and I will mark it as correct.  Thank you!

Comment: i cant verify your "other application" so i cant comment on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default spring boot starts up either as a web application or a reactive application depending on what libraries you have on your classpath.

But you can also tell the framwork to not start up the webserver by explicitly setting the `WebApplicationType` to `None`

here is an example:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainApplication.class)
  .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
  .run(args);
```

or you can set it in the application properties:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

You can read more about it here:

[17.1.5. Create a Non-web Application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.application.non-web-application)

[Spring Boot no web server](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-no-web-server)